# async/await returning exception Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, c#-5.0

I have implemented one of the ActionMethod with Async and Await and result is Task < ActionResult >

```
[Route("Newdiaries/NewTestAsync")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var countryId = Nationalizator.CurrentCountryId;
    var cultureCode = DomainCulture.Current.LCID;

    var channel = GetCandidateServiceChannel("WSHttpBinding_ICandidateService");

    IndividualPersonalInformationDto res = await channel.GetNewIndividualPersonalInformationAsync(new Guid("31764EC2-663D-C996-DB46-08D11B0047E5"), countryId, cultureCode).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var model = new MyTestModel
    {
        Name = res.BusinessId
    };

    return View("NewTestIndex",model);
}
```

It is throwing the **`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]`**  .

I am using Visualstudio 2012 and .Net 4.5 Framework. Please help.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is not an exception but a class.

Comment: Ok, I am not getting partial view rendering , instead it is showing this message :

Comment: My problem is Instead of rendering the Partial View result it is showing : System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]

Comment: @PradeepKumar: Are you absolutely sure you're using ASP.NET MVC **4**?

Comment: Yes, I am using Asp.net MVC 4 and .net framework 4.5

Comment: Share your view (and partial). You should also clarify your title because this question has nothing to do with exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is that you are switching from HttpContextThread , try to remove the .ConfigureAwait(false) please , i think it will solve your problems :)